# Node.js Get video duration on upload

Tags: node.js, video, video-streaming, multer

I'm uploading a video through an `express` call and using `multer` for resumable uploads. I forward the buffer directly to GoogleCloud Storage and don't want to save the file at all on my server.

Is there a server-side way to check for the duration (length) of the video file using only `req.file.buffer` ?

My code looks very similar to [this example](https://gist.github.com/nparsons08/4eb23c5a8e205272e3b382730be617fe#file-controller-js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ npm install --save get-video-duration
I really don't need to explain any further. and look up the npm doc for get video durration